# Trying to mock IntConsumer with Mockito fails

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm trying to mock IntConsumer:

```
class TickerServiceImplTest {
@Test
void testRunIterations() {
    TickerServiceImpl tickerService = new TickerServiceImpl();
    int ticksToRun = 100;
    tickerService.setTicksToRun(ticksToRun);
    IntConsumer intConsumerMock = mock(IntConsumer.class);
    tickerService.run(intConsumerMock);
    verify(intConsumerMock, times(ticksToRun));
}
```

and it fails on the 'verify' with below error code:

`Method threw 'org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException' exception. 
Cannot evaluate $java.util.function.IntConsumer$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$3ee084c4.toString()`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Include the full error message you get.

Comment: The mocked `intConsumerMock` must be injected into the `TickerServiceImpl` for the mock to work. Would need you to add details around how `IntConsumer` is being used within `TickerServiceImpl`.

Comment: I added the injection, but it doesn't matter. It still fails at the same point with the same exception.

Comment: The `verify()` looks like it's used incorrectly. You're not calling any method to verify from the `intConsumer` class. [Example](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verify-T-): `verify(mock,times(1)).someMethod("some arg");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Mockito what method it is supposed to verify on the `IntConsumer` mock. Your verification code should look something like:

```java
verify(intConsumerMock, times(ticksToRun)).accept(anyInt());
```

See for example the tutorial at [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-verify).